# How can i insert a C# list into a Div?

Tags: c#, asp.net, list, webforms

I have a C# list:

```
List<string> Listtags =  GetListTag.GetTagList().ToList();
```

And, I would like to put it into a Div:

```
<div id="tags">
    <ul>
        <li><This should be populated with my list></li>
         //This list can have any number of items depending on how big my list tags is
    </ul>
</div>
```

Could someone show me how to do this?

Comment: Do you work with WebForms or MVC ?

Comment: Does any one know if canvas is supported in webforms Visual studio?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using ASP.NET, you could use a [`BulletedList`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.bulletedlist.aspx) webserver control:

```
<asp:BulletedList ID="BulletedList1" runat="server"
    BulletStyle="Circle" 
    DisplayMode="Text">
</asp:BulletedList>
```

and in codebehind:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        List<string> Listtags = GetListTag.GetTagList().ToList();
        Listtags.ForEach(t => BulletedList1.Items.Add(t));
    }
}
```

**Edit**: *"I want to add something like this::: Listtags.ForEach(t => BulletedList1.Items.Add(t),"$tag$ "); weight being a variable in my code"*

So i assume that you want to add hyperlinks and apply a different css class on the items.

```
<asp:BulletedList ID="BulletedList1" runat="server"
    CssClass="TagList"
    DisplayMode="HyperLink">
</asp:BulletedList>
```

and for example the css:

```
<style>
.TagList a {text-decoration:none}
.TagList a:link {text-decoration:none}
.TagList a:visited {text-decoration: none; color: blue}
.TagList a:hover {text-decoration: underline; color: red}
</style>
```

and how you add the links dynamically(the value of the ListItem is the URL):

```
Listtags.ForEach(t => 
     BulletedList1.Items.Add(new ListItem(t, browseUrl + "?tag=$urlencodetag$"))
);
```

Comment: Will my JavaScript file Treat a asp:BulletedList like a normal list?

Comment: @Pomster: Yes, the [BulletedList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228101.aspx) control creates an unordered or ordered (numbered) list of items, which render as HTML **ul** or **ol** elements, respectively.

Comment: Yes, that's the aspx markup of the BulletedList. Insert it wherever you like.

Comment: Thanks tim i will try it out now

Comment: If i swapped DisplayMode= to "Link"> would it then become a link and how would i go about adding a Anchor tag to my items? I would like to style them with a Style sheet that styles my div #tagCloud A

Comment: @Pomster: a link is a anchor tag. Why don't you test it? The value property of the item will be the url then. If you have other problems, aks  another question.

Comment: I want to add something like this::: Listtags.ForEach(t => BulletedList1.Items.Add(t),"<a class='weight$weight$' href='" + browseUrl + "?tag=$urlencodetag$'>$tag$</a> "); weight being a variable in my code

Comment: :) thanks il check it out now. i just posed the question http://stackoverflow.com/q/10597804/1356321

Comment: The name 'browseUrl' does not exist in the current context. Could you check out my question, it has more details, and since you already know whats going on i'm sure you will be able to answer it.

Comment: @Pomster: Of course it doesn't exist. I've only posted it because you have noted it in your comment, so i asumed that you know what it is ;)  Sorry, i'm running out of time. So i cannot look further into your new question.

Answer (score 7):

you can also use Repeater

```
<ul>
    <asp:Repeater runat="server" id="R">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <li><%# Container.DataItem %></li>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
</ul>
```

and in runtime

```
List<string> ListTags =  GetListTag.GetTagList().ToList();
R.DataSource = ListTags;
R.DataBind();
```

Comment: Could you explain what does what, where would i put Listtags (my list)?

Answer (score 4):

Use   [asp:bulletedList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.bulletedlist.aspx) and your list will be much easier.

```
<div id="tags">
    <asp:BulletedList id="blTabs" 
      BulletStyle="Disc"
      DisplayMode="LinkButton" 
      runat="server">
    </asp:BulletedList>
</div>
```

Code Behind:

```
    ListItem li = new ListItem();
    li.Value = "html text";  //html goes here i.e.  xtab1.html
    li.Text = "New Text";  //text name goes i.e. here tab1
    blTabs.Items.Add(li);
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are using MVC3 you can do something like the following:

```
<div id="tags">
  <ul>
  @foreach(var item in Model.Listtags)
  {
    <li>@item.YourPropertyName</li>
  }
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I see, he can use this answer for future purposes ;-)

Answer (score 2):

In Asp.Net

```
<ul id = "myul" runat = "server">
</ul>
```

In Code Behind (In Page Load I suppose or button click)

```
Listtags.ForEach(x => new ListItem(){Text = x });
```

Comment: How will it know witch div i'm refering to?

Comment: div id="tags">
      <ul id = "MyList">
        <li></li>
      </ul>
    </div> Like so?

Comment: @NikhilAgrawal - you need to make <ul id = "myul">  as runat= sever otherwise how its accessible in your codebehind file..